# Translating async generator into sync one

Tags: python, generator, python-asyncio

Imagine we have an original API that returns a generator (it really is a mechanisms that brings pages/chunks of results from a server while the providing a simple generator to the user, and lets him iterate over these results one by one. For simplicity:

```py
# Original sync generator
def get_results():
     # fetch from server
     yield 1
     yield 2
     # fetch next page
     yield 3
     yield 4
     # ....
```

Now there is a need to implement an asyncio version of the API, however we need to keep the old API operational as well. This is where things get complicated, we kind of want to translate an async generator into sync one, but I can't find an elegant way to do that. The best I could make work so far is "fetch all result into a list first, then provide a fake sync generator on that list". Which kind of defeats the purpose:

```py
# Async generator
async def get_results_async():
     # await fetch from server
     yield 1
     yield 2
     # await fetch next page
     yield 3
     yield 4
     # ....


# Backward compatible sync generator
def get_results():

    async def gather_all_results():
        res = []
        async for i in get_results_async():
            res.append(i)
        return res

    res = asyncio.run(gather_all_results())
    for i in res:
        yield i
```

Is there a better, more elegant way to do that without fetching all the results before returning them?

Thanks

Comment: I realize this question was asked a few days ago, but I wonder why you want to write a new version of get_results() instead of just using the old version.  The new version creates, runs and stops an event loop, so it will perform worse than the old version.  It won't work in any context where the event loop is already running.  Your approach seems like a lot of unnecessary work for a poor outcome.

Comment: @PaulCornelius the actual code within get results fetches a bunch of paginated data. The original one uses urllib for that, the new async one uses aiohttp. The main reason is not to maintain two parallel code paths doing pretty much the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the reason that asyncio is contagious, it's hard to write elegant code to integrate asyncio code into the old codes. For the scenario above, the flowing code is a little better, but I don't think it's elegant enough.

```
async def get_results_async():
    # await fetch from server
    yield 1
    yield 2
    # await fetch next page
    yield 3
    yield 4
    # ....


# Backward compatible sync generator
def get_results():
    gen = get_results_async()
    while True:
        try:
            yield asyncio.run(gen.__anext__())
        except StopAsyncIteration:
            break
```

And you can re-use your event loop and not to create a new one.

```
async def get_results_async():
    # await fetch from server
    yield 1
    yield 2
    # await fetch next page
    yield 3
    yield 4
    # ....

# loop that you save in somewhere.
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

# Backward compatible sync generator
def get_results():
    gen = get_results_async()
    while True:
        try:
            yield loop.run_until_complete(gen.__anext__())
        except StopAsyncIteration:
            break
```

Comment: This code works, but with some more complex async inside it only return the first item from get_results_async - don't understand why

Comment: Mind that you are placing try/except in a hot loop. This is a highly inefficient and inadvisable pattern. Placing `while` inside `try` is a way better idea.

Comment: @sonium I have the same issue and asked the question in another thread. Do you managed to solve your issue ? Was it related to nested async generator ?

Comment: When I run this, I get an error "RuntimeError: asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop". Any advice?