# Nested async-to-sync generator stops at first iteration when executing each iteration individually with asyncio.run

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I’m working on a async library that intends to provide a sync support. For that I use `asgiref` but for demonstration purpose i’ll run `asyncio` that has the same issue.

I want to wrap an async function that returns an async generator into a decorator that will transform this result into a classic generator. **I need to do this without consuming the source generator because I might handle a very large amount of data during this process.** So I need to yield items one at a time while synchronising is a classic python context.

This subject was discussed in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71580727/translating-async-generator-into-sync-one) for a non-nested async generator case, and a user complained about the same issue I encountered today in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71580727/translating-async-generator-into-sync-one#comment127339112_71581122)

I’ve summarised my issue into this example:

```
import asyncio


async def async_generator_source():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3


async def async_generator_wrapper():
    async for item in async_generator_source():
        yield f"source says: {item}"


def sync_generator_wrapper():
    async_generator = async_generator_wrapper()
    try:
        while True:
            print(asyncio.run(async_generator.__anext__()))
    except StopAsyncIteration:
        print("stop async iteration received")


sync_generator_wrapper()
```

I expect this output:

```
source says: 1
source says: 2
source says: 3
stop async iteration received
```

But instead I have this output:

```
source says: 1
stop async iteration received
```

How could I fix this behaviour?

Please remember that `async_generator_source` content should not be stored in a list since it is in my use case a very large set of data.

Answer (score 2):

[`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-runner.html#asyncio.run) will shutdown async generators when it is done, similar to calling the [`shutdown_asyncgens`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.shutdown_asyncgens) method of an event loop:

> This function runs the passed coroutine, taking care of managing the asyncio event loop, *finalizing asynchronous generators*, and closing the threadpool.

So in your case you cannot use `asyncio.run` multiple times to keep executing the same async generator.

You can make your code generate the expected output by getting a reference to the asyncio event loop and calling its [`run_until_complete`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_until_complete) method for executing each iteration of the async generator.

```
import asyncio

async def async_generator_source():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3

async def async_generator_wrapper():
    async for item in async_generator_source():
        yield f"source says: {item}"

def sync_generator_wrapper():
    async_generator = async_generator_wrapper()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()  # this line added
    try:
        while True:
            print(loop.run_until_complete(async_generator.__anext__()))  # this line changed
    except StopAsyncIteration:
        print("stop async iteration received")

sync_generator_wrapper()
```